# Trigger ripple effect on form submit by enter key

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a simple form with submit button. When i click the button, there is a nice ripple effect. I want the same ripple effect to appear when a user submits the form using the enter key. I couldn't find how to do it.

using angular 6 with the latest material version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `keydown.enter` event listener to your form, which will trigger [button](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api#MatButton)'s ripple:

```
<form (keydown.enter)="btn.ripple.launch({centered:true})">
  <input>
  <button #btn mat-button>Click me!</button>
</form>
```

please note, I added `btn` template reference to mat button.

If you want to trigger the ripple from your ts file:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatButton} from '@angular/material';
  .
  .
  .
@ViewChild('btn') btn: MatButton;
  .
  .
  .
ripple() {
  this.btn.ripple.launch({
    centered: true
  });
}
```

and your HTML should look like:

```
<form (keydown.enter)="ripple()">
  <input>
  <button #btn mat-button>Click me!</button>
</form>
```

**USING `ngSubmit` instead of `keydown.enter` will also work:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="ripple()">
  <input>
  <button #btn mat-button>Click me!</button>
</form>
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgtkkz?file=app/button-overview-example.ts)